# Count a specific value inside a php array

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I want to count how many products are in a certain category. So I looped the table containing products inside the table of the categories and looked up how to count the array but I can't get it to work.

At the moment I have the following code:

```
  // Productcategorieen
  $pcat                 = "SELECT * FROM `snm_categories` WHERE parent_id = $pid and published = 1";
  $pcatcon          = $conn->query($pcat);
  while ($pcat      = $pcatcon->fetch_assoc()){
    if($pcat['id'] != ''){
      // Aantal producten binnen een categorie
      $aantal       = "SELECT * FROM `snm_content` WHERE catid = ".$pcat['id']." and state = 1";
      $aantalcon        = $conn->query($aantal);
      while ($aantal    = $aantalcon->fetch_assoc()){
        $count = array_count_values($aantal);
        $result = $count['id'];
        echo '<pre>';
        print_r($aantal);
        echo '</pre>';
      }

      echo $result;

      $productcatoverzicht .= '
      <li class="cat-item"><a href="&'.$pcat['alias'].'">'.$pcat['title'].'</a><span class="count">(9)</span>
                        </li>';
    }
  }
  echo $productcatoverzicht;
```

But when I echo `$result` I get the following message:

`Warning: array_count_values() expects parameter 1 to be array, null given in /home/website/public_html/_extern/website/catalogus.php on line 452`

This is the output (well not all of it, but one entry) when I do `print_r($aantalvar)` :

```
Array
(
    [0] => 5
    [id] => 5
    [1] => 79
    [asset_id] => 79
    [2] => Product 1
    [title] => Product 1
    [3] => product-1
    [alias] => product-1
    [4] => 
    [introtext] => 
    [5] => 
    [fulltext] => 
    [6] => 1
    [state] => 1
    [7] => 18
    [catid] => 18
    [8] => 2017-08-01 08:15:33
    [created] => 2017-08-01 08:15:33
    [9] => 360
    [created_by] => 360
    [10] => 
    [created_by_alias] => 
    [11] => 2017-08-01 08:15:33
    [modified] => 2017-08-01 08:15:33
    [12] => 0
    [modified_by] => 0
    [13] => 0
    [checked_out] => 0
    [14] => 0000-00-00 00:00:00
    [checked_out_time] => 0000-00-00 00:00:00
    [15] => 2017-08-01 08:15:33
    [publish_up] => 2017-08-01 08:15:33
    [16] => 0000-00-00 00:00:00
    [publish_down] => 0000-00-00 00:00:00
    [17] => {"image_intro":"","float_intro":"","image_intro_alt":"","image_intro_caption":"","image_fulltext":"","float_fulltext":"","image_fulltext_alt":"","image_fulltext_caption":""}
    [images] => {"image_intro":"","float_intro":"","image_intro_alt":"","image_intro_caption":"","image_fulltext":"","float_fulltext":"","image_fulltext_alt":"","image_fulltext_caption":""}
    [18] => {"urla":false,"urlatext":"","targeta":"","urlb":false,"urlbtext":"","targetb":"","urlc":false,"urlctext":"","targetc":""}
    [urls] => {"urla":false,"urlatext":"","targeta":"","urlb":false,"urlbtext":"","targetb":"","urlc":false,"urlctext":"","targetc":""}
    [19] => {"show_title":"","link_titles":"","show_tags":"","show_intro":"","info_block_position":"","show_category":"","link_category":"","show_parent_category":"","link_parent_category":"","show_author":"","link_author":"","show_create_date":"","show_modify_date":"","show_publish_date":"","show_item_navigation":"","show_icons":"","show_print_icon":"","show_email_icon":"","show_vote":"","show_hits":"","show_noauth":"","urls_position":"","alternative_readmore":"","article_layout":"","show_publishing_options":"","show_article_options":"","show_urls_images_backend":"","show_urls_images_frontend":""}
    [attribs] => {"show_title":"","link_titles":"","show_tags":"","show_intro":"","info_block_position":"","show_category":"","link_category":"","show_parent_category":"","link_parent_category":"","show_author":"","link_author":"","show_create_date":"","show_modify_date":"","show_publish_date":"","show_item_navigation":"","show_icons":"","show_print_icon":"","show_email_icon":"","show_vote":"","show_hits":"","show_noauth":"","urls_position":"","alternative_readmore":"","article_layout":"","show_publishing_options":"","show_article_options":"","show_urls_images_backend":"","show_urls_images_frontend":""}
    [20] => 1
    [version] => 1
    [21] => 0
    [ordering] => 0
    [22] => 
    [metakey] => 
    [23] => 
    [metadesc] => 
    [24] => 1
    [access] => 1
    [25] => 0
    [hits] => 0
    [26] => {"robots":"","author":"","rights":"","xreference":""}
    [metadata] => {"robots":"","author":"","rights":"","xreference":""}
    [27] => 0
    [featured] => 0
    [28] => *
    [language] => *
    [29] => 
    [xreference] => 
)
```

How can I count how much [id] occurs in the entire array?

One issue: there are multiple arrays that come from `$aantalvar` like you can see here:

[image]

I need to know how much `[id]` occurs in all of them.

Comment: Change `$pcatcon->fetch_array()` to `$pcatcon->fetch_assoc()` then the array will only contain one of everything instead of 2 of everything

Comment: How would `$productcat['id'] != ''` ever evaluate as false? Isn't `id` an auto incremented primary key?

Comment: @MagnusEriksson For some reason I get an extra empty result using my code, so this is more like a dirty fix to make sure id exists and is not empty.

Comment: @RiggsFolly I still get two arrays with fetch_assoc the only difference is that array is not numbered anymore.

Comment: There's a lot of issue in this code. You do: `$count = array_count_values($aantalvar);` and in the row below, you're doing `$counts['id']` (not the same variable name)

Comment: Instead of `foreach($pcatcr as $productcat){`, have your code inside the first `while`-loop directly. You do the same again inside the `foreach`-loop for the second query.

Comment: You could probably also do what you want with only one query, using a `JOIN`-statement instead of doing a bunch of queries inside a loop. Even though I'm not really getting what it is you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson There is an amount of products linked to a category, I want to count all products inside a category and show the amount after every categoryname in a looped list. So the final result will be a list of categories with the amount of products within that category next to it.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson I edited the code, both are now in while loops, but I still get two arrays. Look: https://gyazo.com/aae522832838f7ed51c26c3023c4ebad How can I count id for both of them? The result I end up with should be 2, since there are two products.

Comment: @twan have you tried my answer

Answer (score 0):

You may try it .

```
// Productcategorieen

  $pcat                 = "SELECT * FROM `snm_categories` WHERE parent_id = $pid and published = 1";
  $pcatcon          = $conn->query($pcat);
  while ($pcat      = $pcatcon->fetch_assoc()){
    if($pcat['id'] != ''){

      // Aantal producten binnen een categorie

      $aantal       = "SELECT * FROM `snm_content` WHERE catid = ".$pcat['id']." and state = 1";

      $aantalcon        = $conn->query($aantal);

      $aantal    = $aantalcon->fetch_assoc();

      if(is_null($aantal)){
        $total = 0;  
      }else{
        $total = count($aantal);  
      }



      $productcatoverzicht .= '
      <li class="cat-item"><a href="&'.$pcat['alias'].'">'.$pcat['title'].'</a><span class="count">'.$total.'</span>
                        </li>';

    }
  }
  echo $productcatoverzicht;
```

Comment: For some reason a category that has products under it always shows 30, this means it counts how much values are in the array (all of them because there are 30). I don't need that, I need to know how much [id] occurs in the array. Which is two times because at the moment I only have two products.

Comment: did not understand what you are expecting  ? it possible show the `snm_content` table.

Comment: You can use DISTICT Keyword when selecting the rocords on behalf of category_id , then disticnt records will be returned

Comment: @twan what should be your exact output can you show that

Comment: @vjytiwari I tried that, it shows the numbers next to it without errors or warnings so that is good, but all numbers show only 1. I added 2 products to a category, and it still shows one next to that category name. (here: https://gyazo.com/2605ccb1410d7ad6abce165c825f2b47 the last one has two products but still only shows 1)

Comment: i think , you also checking `state` column ? so may be other product have `state` 0 ?

Comment: Yes I do, but their state is all 1.